# PHP read dir and return array with paths of related image links

Tags: php, arrays, image

I try to write a function which returns an array of images for a jQuery image slider.

And now I'm getting a bit stuck in getting the right logical code. And I'm thinking mabey the whole structure is wrong?
I can get the right path for 1 file, but an array of the related files doesn't seem to work.

```
##info past to the function:
$id = '11101';
$dir = "myimgdir/";
$thumbs = 'TN';
$medium = 'M';

##the files in the dir are named like this:
11101x1xTN //thumbnail
11101x2xTN
11101x3xTN
11101x1xM //some img but in medium size
11101x2xM
11101x3xM
```

So:

```
$dir = "$dir$id/";      
$get_opts = array($thumbs, $medium);

// array to hold return value 
$retval = array();

   //full dir
   $fulldir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/$dir"; 

$d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getImages: Failed opening directory $dir for reading"); 
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {

  $fullpath = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");
  $file_extension = end(explode('.', $fullpath));
  $file_name = basename($entry, $file_extension);   


 ####here I get stuck
    foreach ($get_opts as $get_opt) {           
        if (strpos($file_name, $get_opt)) { //so 11101x1xTN gontains TN
            $retval[] = array( 
                'TN'      => "/$dir$entry", 
                'TNsize'  => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry"),

                ####how to return the medium path as well (11101x1xM)
                'M'  => "/$dir", 
            );
        }           
    }



}

$d->close();    
return $retval;
```

Comment: Why `$fullpath = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");`? just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the perfect opportunity to use [PHPs `glob()` function](http://php.net/glob).

```
<?php
$thumbs = glob('*TN*');
foreach ($thumbs as $filename) {
    $image_path = '/' . $dir . $filename;
    $medium_image_path = str_replace('TN', 'M', $image_path);
    if(!is_file($medium_image_path)) {
        $medium_image_path = '';
    }
    $retval[] = array( 
            'TN'      => $image_path,
            'TNsize'  => getimagesize($image_path),
            'M'  => $medium_image_path, 
        );
}
?>
```